# Does continuity in product space imply equicontinuity?

Tags: metric-spaces

I was given a problem, which asked to show that if X is a metric space and if F is a continuous function from the product space (of X with itself) to real, then the family of functions : {F(x,y):x belongs to X}, indexed by x, is equicontinuous. I had no problem in proving the fact under the assumption that F is **uniformly** continuous on the product space. I somehow have a doubt about its truth if only continuity of F is assumed. Can anyone help me clarify this doubt? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for a counterexample. There are easy ones. Take e.g. $X = \mathbb{R}$ to have something concrete.

Comment: So, you mean that the problem is not true if only continuity and not uniform continuity is assumed?

Comment: As you suspected, continuity alone is not enough.